# How to set browser microphone and camera permission with button click react

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, camera

I am using `permissionStatus.state === "granted"` to detect status.

How can I change it?

[image: Image description]

Comment: Please provide some code to get an answer according to your code

Answer (score 2):

Demo here: https://codepen.io/kennyalvizuris/pen/oMXezO

```
        class Permissions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      havePermissions: false,
    };
    this.checkPermissions = this.checkPermissions.bind(this);
  }

  checkPermissions() {
    const permissions = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
    permissions.then((stream) => {
      alert('accepted the permissions');
      this.setState(((prevState) => {
        havePermissions: !prevState.havePermissions
      }));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState(((prevState) => {
        havePermissions: false
      }));
      console.log(`${err.name} : ${err.message}`)
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.checkPermissions}>
      Permissions button {this.state.havePermissions}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Permissions />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: it does not work when access is blocked. i want to change exactly this state.